project--vc-list-files wrong-type-argument stringp, nil when using project.el's project file search function over TRAMP
What it sounds like. Trying to use a project in a Podman (distrobox) container, and find-file works fine, so does running an LSP inside the container and transparently talking to it via Emacs, and so does Eshell, but Project.el fails with:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  split-string(nil "\0" t)
  project--vc-list-files("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/" Git nil)
  #f(compiled-function (dir) #<bytecode 0x127170807f0d9786>)("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/")
  mapcan(#f(compiled-function (dir) #<bytecode 0x127170807f0d9786>) ("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/"))
  #f(compiled-function (project &optional dirs) #<bytecode 0xefa9d2ee2fa27b8>)((vc Git "/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/") ("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/"))
  apply(#f(compiled-function (project &optional dirs) #<bytecode 0xefa9d2ee2fa27b8>) (vc Git "/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/") ("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/"))
  project-files((vc Git "/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/") ("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/"))
  project-find-file-in(#("with-eval-after-load" 0 20 (face font-lock-comment-face fontified t)) ("/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/") (vc Git "/podman:development:~/Development/embryo-engine/") nil)
  project-find-file(nil)
  funcall-interactively(project-find-file nil)
  project-switch-project("/podman:development:./Development/embryo-engine/")
  funcall-interactively(project-switch-project "/podman:development:./Development/embryo-engine/")
  command-execute(project-switch-project)


A mention of your Emacs version (and/or version of the project package) could help.

@Dmitry emacs 29.3, project.el 0.9.8, and I've resolved the problem for now by doing this: https://gist.github.com/alexispurslane/890ea9971787c979f8c59c8decf132c4

Thanks. Can you reproduce the same problem using the ssh transport, for example? Both project-find-file and project-find-regexp seem to work fine for me over Tramp using the ssh transport.

If your problem is specific to the podman transport, it will be a good idea to file a detailed bug report, M-x report-emacs-bug.

Aye, I'll do that. It works fine over SSH, and in fact the code I used to fix podman breaks SSH. Hmpf.

Thank you. This is the report, for posterity: https://debbugs.gnu.org/71200
